# Haskell "parse error on input ‘=’"

Tags: haskell

I am doing some haskell exercises to learn the language and I have a syntax error I was hoping someone could help me with:

```
-- Split a list l at element k into a tuple: The first part up to and including k, the second part after k
-- For example "splitAtIndex 3 [1,1,1,2,2,2]" returns ([1,1,1],[2,2,2])
splitAtIndex k l = ([l !! x | x <- firstHalfIndexes], [l !! x | x <- firstHalfIndexes])
    where   firstHalfIndexes = [0..k-1]
            secondHalfIndexes = [k..(length l-1)]
```

The syntax error is "parse error on input ‘=’" and seems to be coming from my second where clause, but I can't work out why the first where clause is ok but not the second?

Comment: I can compile it just fine (although the output is not as expected).

Comment: @Mephy You have to click "edit" to see the actual code. StackOverflow converts tabs to spaces in code blocks (naughty, naughty!) with tabstops every four columns.

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell Report specifies that tab characters flesh out text to the next multiple of eight. Your code appears to assume that it gets fleshed out to the next multiple of four. (My best guess. Might also be configured to be five or six, but those settings seem less popular than four.)

See [my page on tabs](http://dmwit.com/tabs) for ideas on how to safely use tabs in Haskell code; or else do what most other folks do and configure your editor to expand tabs to spaces.

For an example of the style I use, your current code looks like this to the compiler (using `>` to mark tabs and `_` for spaces):

```
splitAtIndex_..._=_...
>       where_> firstHalfIndexes_=_...
>       >       >       secondHalfIndexes_=_...
```

I would write it to look like this to the compiler:

```
splitAtIndex_..._=_...
>       where_> firstHalfIndexes_=_...
>       ______> secondHalfIndexes_=_...
```

This also looks correct with four-space tabstops (and indeed any size tabstop):

```
splitAtIndex_..._=_...
>   where_> firstHalfIndexes_=_...
>   ______> secondHalfIndexes_=_...
```

(Actually, I would probably just use one space after `where` rather than a space and a tab, but that's an aesthetics thing, not really a technical one.)